# Interactive brokers TWS API error message

Tags: python

Below is the error stack trace of a program given by my teacher to run:

```
 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "D:/miscellaneous/Investment/programming/Chris Wong 20201218/real_python_trading_course 202102/thinkific/ib_api/>     b_api_framework-test01_20210614.py"
 ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:hfarm
 ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
 ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
 ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
 ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
 ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:hkhmds
 ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
 ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefnj
 unhandled exception in EReader thread
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\reader.py", line 34, in run
     data = self.conn.recvMsg()
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\connection.py", line 99, in recvMsg
     buf = self._recvAllMsg()
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\connection.py", line 119, in _recvAllMsg
     buf = self.socket.recv(4096)
 OSError: [WinError 10038] 嘗試操作的對象不是通訊端。
 Exception in thread Thread-2:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\client.py", line 239, in run
     self.decoder.interpret(fields)
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\decoder.py", line 1280, in interpret
     handleInfo.processMeth(self, iter(fields))
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibapi-9.76.1-py3.7.egg\ibapi\decoder.py", line 271, in processContractDataMsg
     contract.contract.symbol = decode(str, fields)
 AttributeError: 'ContractDetails' object has no attribute 'contract'

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/miscellaneous/Investment/programming/Chris Wong 20201218/real_python_trading_course 202102/thinkific/ib_api/ib_api_framework-test01_20210614.py", line 686, in <module>
     resolved_ibcontract = app.resolve_ib_contract(ibcontract)
   File "D:/miscellaneous/Investment/programming/Chris Wong 20201218/real_python_trading_course 202102/thinkific/ib_api/ib_api_framework-test01_20210614.py", line 342, in resolve_ib_contract
     new_contract_details = self.contract_details_queue.get(timeout = MAX_WAIT_SECONDS)
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\queue.py", line 178, in get
     raise Empty
 _queue.Empty

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this, as the code is my teacher's intellectual property and I can't expose it.

*I have bought a new laptop & installed anaconda. It works now, so it should not be caused by the program.

Comment: Your teacher forgot to handle an exception. You should be asking them this question

Comment: How do you know?
Is it by 'unhandled exception in EReader thread'?
or 
'Exception in thread Thread-2:'?

He is not responsive and I have not much chance to meet him. I can only solve it by myself now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

```py
contract.contract.symbol = decode(str, fields)
AttributeError: 'ContractDetails' object has no attribute 'contract'
```

I think you meant to do:

```py
contract.symbol = decode(str, fields)
```

Comment: It is the code by interactive brokers' software. I think it is not supposed to make change.

Comment: ah, you're right, sorry. Well, it's likely a bug then. I would ask on their official forum, if they have one.